# multiprocessing.RawArray operation

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, ctypes, mmap

I read that `RawArray` can be shared between proceses without being copied, and wanted to understand how it is possible in Python.

I saw in [sharedctypes.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/multiprocessing/sharedctypes.py), that a `RawArray` is constructed from a `BufferWrapper` from [heap.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/multiprocessing/heap.py), then nullified with `ctypes.memset`.

`BufferWrapper` is made of an `Arena` object, which itself is built from an `mmap` (or 100 mmaps in windows, see line 40 in [heap.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/multiprocessing/heap.py))

I read that the `mmap` system call is actually used to allocate memory in Linux/BSD, and the Python module uses [MapViewOfFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-mapviewoffile) for windows.

`mmap` seems handy then. It seems to be able to work directly with `mp.pool`-

```
from struct import pack
from mmap import mmap

def pack_into_mmap(idx_nums_tup):

    idx, ints_to_pack = idx_nums_tup
    pack_into(str(len(ints_to_pack)) + 'i', shared_mmap, idx*4*total//2 , *ints_to_pack)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    total = 5 * 10**7
    shared_mmap = mmap(-1, total * 4)
    ints_to_pack = range(total)

    pool = Pool()
    pool.map(pack_into_mmap, enumerate((ints_to_pack[:total//2], ints_to_pack[total//2:])))
```

My question is -

How does the multirocessing module know not to copy the `mmap` based `RawArray` object between processes, like it does with "regular" python objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[[Python 3.Docs]: multiprocessing - Process-based parallelism](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=process#module-multiprocessing) serializes / deserializes data exchanged between processes using a proprietary protocol: [[Python 3.Docs]: pickle - Python object serialization](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#module-pickle) (and from here the terms: *pickle* / *unpickle*).

According to [[Python 3.Docs]: pickle - object.**__getstate__**()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#object.__getstate__):

> Classes can further influence how their instances are pickled; if the class defines the method [__getstate__()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#object.__getstate__), it is called and the returned object is pickled as the contents for the instance, instead of the contents of the instance’s dictionary. If the [__getstate__()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#object.__getstate__) method is absent, the instance’s [__dict__](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#object.__dict__) is pickled as usual.

As seen in (*Win* variant of) *Arena.__getstate__*, (class chain: *sharedctypes.RawArray -> heap.BufferWrapper - > heap.Heap -> heap.Arena*), only the metadata (*name* and *size*) are *pickled* for the *Arena* instance, but not the buffer itself.

Conversely, in *__setstate__*, the buffer is constructed based on the (above) metadata.

Comment: So it's not about avoiding pickle, rather pickling minimal metadata. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, indeed. :)

Comment: follow up - what happens in the example above, where raw mmap is used without a class that defines __getstate()__? ?Does the entire memory region get pickled?

Comment: Then the default pickling mechanism is used, which unfortunately I don't know at this time. Did you try pickling such a (big) memory object to see whether the result size is comparable?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickle.dump. (or *dumps*).

Comment: tried `dumps`, i get `cannot pickle 'mmap.mmap' object`