# Understanding shared_memory in Python 3.8

Tags: python, pickle, python-multiprocessing, shared-memory, mmap

I'm trying to understand some of `shared_memory`'s operation.

Looking at the [source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/multiprocessing/shared_memory.py) , it looks like the module uses `shm_open()` for UNIX environments, and `CreateFileMapping` \ `OpenFileMapping` on windows, combined with `mmap`.

I understand from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56495471/multiprocessing-rawarray-operation), that in order to avoid a thorough serialization / deserialization by `pickle`, one needs to implement `__setstate__()` and `__getstate__()` explicitly for his shared datatype.

I do not see any such implementation in `shared_memory.py`.

How does `shared_memory` circumvent the pickle treatment?

Also, on a Windows machine, this alone seems to survive accross interpreters:

```
from mmap import mmap

shared_size = 12
shared_label = "my_mem"

mmap(-1, shared_size , shared_label)
```

Why then is `CreateFileMapping` \ `OpenFileMapping` needed here?

Comment: I think `shared_memory` dodges pickling because it only provides a `memoryview` that wraps the shared buffer. You can read and write raw bytes, but you cannot pass objects to `SharedMemory`. It has no interface for that. To get an object into memory, you would need to serialize it to raw bytes and blast those into the buffer. Pickling creeps back into the equation because of the serialization step. Got no clue on the second question. Lastly, note that `mmap` plays a role in both the unix and windows branches in the constructor. See line 111. Disclaimer, not an authority on anything.

Answer (score 15):

> How does `shared_memory` circumvent the pickle treatment?

I think you are confusing *shared ctypes* and *shared objects* between processes.

First, you don't have to use the sharing mechanisms provided by `multiprocessing` in order to get shared objects, you can just wrap basic primitives such as `mmap` / Windows-equivalent or get fancier using any API that your OS/kernel provides you.

Next, the second link you mention regarding how copy is done and how `__getstate__` defines the behavior of the pickling is dependent on you — using the `sharedctypes` module API. You are not forced to perform pickling to share memory between two processes.

In fact, `sharedctypes` is backed by anonymous shared memory which uses: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/multiprocessing/heap.py#L31

Both implementations relies on an `mmap`-like primitive.

Anyway, if you try to copy something using `sharedctype`, you will hit:

- https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/multiprocessing/sharedctypes.py#L98
- https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/multiprocessing/sharedctypes.py#L39
- https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/multiprocessing/sharedctypes.py#L135

And this function is using `ForkingPickler` which will make use of `pickle` and then… ultimately, you'll call `__getstate__` somewhere.

But it's not relevant with `shared_memory`, because `shared_memory` is not really a `ctype`-like object.

You have other ways to share objects between processes, using the Resource Sharer / Tracker API: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/multiprocessing/resource_sharer.py which will rely on `pickle` serialization/deserialization.

But you don't share shared memory through shared memory, right?

When you use: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/multiprocessing/shared_memory.py

You create a block of memory with a unique name, and all processes must have the unique name *before* sharing the memory, otherwise you will not be able to attach it.

Basically, the analogy is:

> You have a group of friends and you all have a unique secret base that only you have the location, you will go on errands, be away from each other, but you can all meet at this unique location.

In order for this to work, you must all know the location before going away from each other. If you do not have it beforehand, you are not certain that you will be able to figure out the place to meet them.

That is the same with the `shared_memory`, you only need its name to open it. You don't share / transfer `shared_memory` between processes. You read into `shared_memory` using its unique name from multiple processes.

As a result, why would you pickle it? You can. You can absolutely pickle it. But that might not be built-in, because it's straightforward to just send the unique name to all your processes through another shared memory channel or anything like that.

There is no circumvention required here. `ShareableList` is just an example of application of `SharedMemory` class. As you can see it here: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/multiprocessing/shared_memory.py#L314

It requires something akin to a unique name, you can use anonymous shared memory also and transmit its name later through another channel (write a temporary file, send it back to some API, whatever).

> Why then is CreateFileMapping \ OpenFileMapping needed here?

Because it depends on your Python interpreter, here you are might be using CPython, which is doing the following:

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/mmapmodule.c#L1440

It's already using `CreateFileMapping` indirectly so that doing `CreateFileMapping` then attaching it is just duplicating the already-done work in CPython.

But, what about others interpreters? Do all interpreters perform the necessary to make `mmap` work on non-POSIX platforms? Maybe the rationale of the developer would be this.

Anyway, it is not surprising that `mmap` would work out of the box.